# Indicate to an ajax process that the delayed job has completed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, comet, delayed-job, polling

I have a Rails 3 app that uses delayed_job to fetch some data (with a class method) when the user hits the page.
How can I indicate to the ajax process that the class method has run (so that I can stop polling)?

**EDIT:**

To clarify, I want to know when the delayed_job has run, not when the ajax process has succeeded.  Then I want to pass the delayed_job completed status to the running ajax process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Typically, the best way to do this is to store, in your database, an indication of the job's progress. For instance:

```
class User
  def perform_calculation
    begin
      self.update_attributes :calculation_status => 'started'
      do_something_complex
      self.update_attributes :calculation_status => 'success' 
    rescue Exception => e
      self.update_attributes :calculation_status => 'error'
    end
  end
end
```

So that when you enqueue the job:

```
User.update_attributes :calculation_status => 'enqueued'
User.send_later :perform_calculation
```

You can query, in your controller, the status of the job:

```
def check_status
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  render :json => @user.calculation_status
end
```

You polling ajax process can then simply call check_status to see how the job is progressing, if it has succeeded or if it has failed.

Comment: Pan is the man! Thanks dude, this worked like a charm. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

With this gem you can have progress tracking directly on the `Delayed::Job` object itself: https://github.com/GBH/delayed_job_progress

Completed jobs are no longer automatically removed, so you can poll against a job until it comes back with `completed` state.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using any JavaScript framework like prototypejs, then in the optional options hash, you usually provide a onComplete and/or onSuccess callback. [API Reference](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request)

Comment: But won't the call succeed no matter what because the job is just being enqueued?